# switch statement variable value extraction

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm currently working on an assignment and have come across the following problem. I'm attempting to extract the string value a and b separately and at the same time somehow, but I only get 1 at a time per switch statement. How do i save the value in a and b so that they have the values at the same time?

```
stringstream convert(c);

int inta;

switch(index)
{
    case 0:
    {
        value1->value(c);
        if(count == 1) {
        gen2value1->value(c);
        }
        if(count == 2) {
        gen2value1->value(c);
        }
        a.assign(c);
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        value2->value(c);
        if(count == 1) {
        gen2value2->value(c);
        }
        if(count == 2) {
        gen2value2->value(c);
        }
        b.assign(c);
        break;
    }
}
cout << "a= " << a << endl;
cout << "b= " << b << endl;
```

I want to get the following output:

```
a= 1
b= 2
```

but I get

```
a= 1
b= 
a= 
b= 2
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete [mcve] and perhaps we can make some sense of that. There's no indication in this code of a loop so you either get the code in the first case, the second, or neither.

Comment: There are closing brackets missing. 7 opening brackets and 5 closing brackets?

Comment: Without outer scope code, the behavior you explained is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using threading here?  Otherwise, ignore answer.

To get the desired output, you would need to move the `cout << "a= " << a << endl;` and `cout << "b= " << b << endl;` into their respective switch case (`a` output being 0 and `b` output being 1) prior to the break statement.

From the code you have the provided, the output currently is as would be expected. What is happening is that thread 0 will run and assign variable `a` with `c` through the first switch case. After it has done that, `break` is called. This then goes to the next statement of the `cout` statements.

For thread 0, the variable `a` has been assigned `c`. However, variable `b` has not been assigned anything. This is why the output has `a= 1  b=`. The same idea applies to the second thread using the second switch case.

The threads are occurring at approximately the same time so they are not picking up on each other assigning values. Hope this has helped!

Comment: I want to be able to use the value of c in the first switch statement and put it into a. Then, the next one is to put the value of the second switch statement c and put that into b. The cout statements are there for me to be able to see if they get the values or not.

Comment: For further understanding, you definitely need to include more code so that, as others have said, there is a minimal reproducible example.  From what you are describing, the only way I can think of having both assignments happen in the same thread instance would be to include `b` being assigned in the same switch case as `a` and vise versa.
My main question here would be about count.  You're using this to get c to assign a and b in the next statements.  
I suggest adding more printing statements so you can try to follow c throughout each thread